# how to implement an event-drive consumer in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am very new to Camel, and have been struggling to understand how to use camel in a specific scenario.
In this scenario, there is a (Java-based) agent that generates actions from time to time. I need an event-driven consumer to get notified of these events. These events will be routed to a 'file' producer (for the time being).

In the camel book, the example is for a polling consumer. I could not find a generic solution for an event-driven consumer.
I came across a similar implementation for JMX :

```
public class JMXConsumer extends DefaultConsumer implements NotificationListener { 

JMXEndpoint jmxEndpoint;    
public JMXConsumer(JMXEndpoint endpoint, Processor processor) { 
    super(endpoint, processor);
    this.jmxEndpoint = endpoint;
}

public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) { 
    try {
        getProcessor().process(jmxEndpoint.createExchange(notification)); 
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        handleException(e); 
    }
}
```

}

Here, the handleNotification is invoked whenever a JMX notification arrives.

I believe I have to do something similar to get my consumer notified whenever the agent generates an action. However, the above handleNotification method is specific to JMX. The web page says: " When implementing your own event-driven consumer, you must identify an analogous event listener method to implement in your custom consumer."

I want to know: How can I identify an analogous event listener, so that my consumer will be notified whenever my agent has an action.

Any advice/link to a web page is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event driven is what camel is.

Any route is actually an event listener.

given the route:

```
from("activemq:SomeQueue").
  bean(MyClass.class);

public class MyBean{
  public void handleEvent(MyEventObject eventPayload){ // Given MyEventObject was sent to this "SomeQueue".
     // whatever processing.
  }
}
```

That would put up an event driven consumer. How to send events then? If you have camel embedded in your app and access to the CamelContext from your event action generator, then you could grab a [Producer Template](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) from it and just fire of your event to whatever endpoint you defined in Camel, such as "seda:SomeQueue".

Otherwise, if your Camel instance is running in another server or instance than your application, then you should use some other transport rather than SEDA. Preferably JMS, but others will do as well, pick and choose. ActiveMQ is my favourite. You can start an embedded activemq instance (intra JVM) easily and connect it to camel by:

```
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent("vm://localhost"));
```

Comment: Thank yo so much for your response. I was particularly wondering how to sent events. Thanks for explaining that as well. Will try this out soon. (I'm new to JEE stuff, so might take a while to figure out all this)

Comment: Good. Updated the answer about different transports, i.e. Seda and ActiveMQ embedded.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I've been struggling with it and just thought I would document my findings for anyone else searching for an answer.

When you create an Endpoint class (extending DefaultEndpoint) you override the following method for creating a consumer:

```
public Consumer createConsumer(Processor processor)
```

In your consumer then, you have access to a Processor - calling 'process' on this processor will create an event and trigger the route.

For example, say you have some Java API that listens for messages, and has some sort of Listener. In my case, the Listener puts incoming messages onto a LinkedBlockingQueue, and my Consumer 'doStart' method looks like this (add your own error handling):

```
@Override
protected void doStart() throws Exception {
    super.doStart();

    // Spawn a new thread that submits exchanges to the Processor
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                IMessage incomingMessage = myLinkedBlockingQueue.take();
                Exchange exchange = getEndpoint().createExchange();
                exchange.getIn().setBody(incomingMessage);
                myProcessor.process(exchange);  
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Now I can put the Component that creates the Endpoint that creates this Consumer in my CamelContext, and use it like this:

```
from("mycomponent:incoming").to("log:messages");
```

And the log message fires every time a new message arrives from the Java API.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Yes, it helped me a lot.

Comment: super.doStart(); is required?

Comment: Probably not, I think my IDE put that in automatically. If you look at the 'doStart()' method in DefaultEndpoint, it just does " // noop ", so I think you can safely remove it